# Does my question require additional context?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

For my question [What is the limit involving `Sum`, `Subsets`, and `RankedMax` as `t` approaches infinity?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/254067/what-is-the-limit-involving-sum-subsets-and-rankedmax-as-t-approaches), I decided not to add additional context as the mathematics behind my code is extremely complex.

Initially I thought [my original question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253820/is-there-a-way-we-can-compute-my-sum-involving-subsets-more-efficiently) would give what I wanted but I decided the solution to my mathematical problem was more complicated. (I wish to state my mathematical problem but it would involve pure mathematics rather than code).

Should I add more context or is my question good as it is?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question was migrated and is no longer in Mathematica Stack Exchange.